# Is Jon mad at Ghost for some reason and is that why he won't acknowledge him?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After watching Ghost return in S8, I was very happy. However, imagine my disappointment when Jon Snow does not even bother to acknowledge his existence for the first three episodes, even sending him to almost certain death charging with the Dothraki horde!

Is there any evidence in the book/show that Jon Snow is mad at Ghost and won't acknowledge him?

Comment: The show is ahead of the books so you won't get an answer there.

Comment: There are very litle scene with ghost becose it's CGI-expensive, and he charge for the drama. Sad to say, but lot of question can be better explain out-universe than in-universe

Comment: How will Ghost know if he's a good boy or not if Jon doesn't tell him every episode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Jon does acknowledge Ghost, although off screen. In the montage in Season 8 Episode 2, "A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms", Ghost is seen standing with Jon and Sam. Presumably they have had other interactions but just off screen.

[image: Ghost, Sam and Jon wait for the battle]

The direwolves overall get little screen time due to budget reasons, in "Battle of the Bastards" I think the budget only allowed for the giant or Ghost. Also it is apparently hard to work with the wolves on set.

> During our conversation, Bauer explained that the lack of direwolves in the last “GoT” season might have had something to do with the fact that regular wolves aren’t as magical to work with.
>
> “The direwolves are tough because you don’t want to get them wrong, so we end up always shooting real wolves and doing a scaling trick with them, but the real wolves only behave in certain ways,” Bauer said.
>
> <sub>[Huffington Post, A Missing 'Game Of Thrones' Character Is Coming Back In Season 8](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/game-of-thrones-ghost-season-8_n_5b7eb066e4b0348585fe242b?guccounter=1&guce_referrer_us=aHR0cHM6Ly9mZWVkbHkuY29tL2kvbGF0ZXN0&guce_referrer_cs=7c6Xg4VB-RF2qq8F2x4jIA)</sub>

In fact in the same interview Bauer goes on to say the following which implies we should be getting more of Ghost in the following 3 episodes.

> “Ghost does show up, and he does some ... he’s very present and does some pretty cool things in Season 8,” he said.
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

Comment: Do we have an out of the universe reason on why Ghost has so little screen time and importance? Like, it's too expensive to make the CGI for Ghost or something on those lines.

Comment: @FernandoRibeiro Added a bit more

Comment: @FernandoRibeiro Dragons eat whatever they want...upto and including the direwolf budget.

Comment: @Ghostiboi The elephant budget, too... I really wanted those elephants.

Comment: And the lighting budget from the looks of things.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I had zero problems watching the latest episode streamed to my TV. Any issues with the show being too dark are down to problems with the quality of the broadcast/stream or the device being used to view it, and the people making the show can't necessarily be blamed for that.

Comment: What evidence do you have to say that they interacted off-screen? It's pretty clear he was added in post-production as an afterthought.

Comment: @Anthony grist that may have been your experience, but a great many people have been publicly saying that the show was hard to watch due to the dark cinematography.